# What are the configuration needed to to do in a MVC ADFS app to use Asure AD SSO

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs

I have a application written in .NET 4.7, C#, asp MVC and its hosted in a clients server. currently they use ADFS SSO and wanted to move to Azure AD. they sent me an xml meta data file and the new certificate. I don't have much knowledge in this and I don't have any access to their Azure AD. I did some research but all the Microsoft tutorials are about starting from hosting an app in our own Azure AD or migrating from ADFS to our own ASURE AD. All i want to know is what are the necessary code changes to the app and how to get those information from the metadata.xml and the certificate. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does the application use adfs sso? How does it do it?

Comment: And when you talk about metadata.xml. is it using SAML? And what client-side library do you use to talk to ADFS?

Answer (score 0):

We  finally got the solution and wonder how come this solution never appeared when we google "how to move from ADFS to AAD". The problem we faced was, the system we did, we setup a login using common algorithm and the client party integrated with ADFS security. Which an area we didn't have any knowledge. but later they forwarded us a mail claiming they wanted to set up Azure AD security and sent us an metadata.xml file.

When we successfully registered an Enterprise app in Azure AD (portal.Azure) with a app name (without hosting in azure) with SSO it allowed us to download certificate and metadata.xml file. That's the xml file they sent us. and we needed to make changes to our web.config using that.

There are two ways to solve this. Either you can read tons of Microsoft article about how to configure this, how to configure that and try adding changes to files and still confused or else you simply install Microsoft Owin (Open Web Interface for .NET) security to system through nuget PM and in the server machine just install [Windows Identity Foundation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331)SDK .

In the location you installed open Windows Identity Foundation SDK\v4.0(in our case) and run fedutl.exe . There you just upload web.config file to the Application configuration box and URL or the local path of the AAD metadata.xml file in the Application URI box. click next , next  selecting options as needed for your requirement and finally click finish ,and Boom your web config file is now configured to use the Azure AAD .

Hope this helps to anyone faced with an similar situation.

Regards